# How to know my pointer will not be deallocated?

Tags: rust

I am working on a Linux-PAM module and I implemented this function to get the user.

```rust
pub fn get_user(pamh: PamHandleT) -> PamResult<&'static CStr> {
    let mut raw_user: *const c_char = ptr::null();
    let r = unsafe { pam_get_user(pamh, &mut raw_user, ptr::null()) };
    if raw_user.is_null() {
        Err(r)
    } else {
        let user = unsafe {CStr::from_ptr(raw_user)};
        Ok(user)
    }
}
```

`pam_get_user` is a C function from libpam that returns a `* const c_char` via its second argument. PAM documentation states that I must not free that pointer to allow interoperability with other modules.

By using the `'static` lifetime for the return value, I believe this value will not be deallocated, is that correct? Maybe I could copy the value to use it in a more Rust-idiomatic way, how could I do that?

Comment: Does it compile now?

Comment: Lifetime annotations don't affect the behaviour of the compiled code. They are only consumed by the borrow checker to verify the code is correct, so they only determine whether the code compiles, not what it does.

Comment: Your code seems to be fine. But I think more rust idiomatic way is to create your own `User` wrapper, which will hold a reference to that `'static CStr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CStr` is responsible for handling the value and in contrast to `CString` it does not allocate or deallocate memory, just like `str` and `String`. You just pass a pointer to it and have to ensure its requirements. Make sure to read [`std::ffi::CStr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ffi/struct.CStr.html) carefully and understand what you are doing.

Your code looks fine so far, so you should be ready to go.

Comment: I don't think it correct, "The pam_end function terminates the PAM transaction and is the last function an application should call in the PAM context. Upon return the handle pamh is no longer valid and all memory associated with it will be invalid. ". i think it's valid as long the handle is valid. https://linux.die.net/man/3/pam_end

Comment: I don't get your point here. There is no call to `pam_end` in the code.

Comment: my point is that a call to pam_end may invalid the pointer and so static lifetime is probably not correct.

Answer (score 1):

You, probably, need to make owned value. This would allocate though.

```rust
pub fn get_user(pamh: PamHandleT) -> PamResult<CString> {
    let mut raw_user: *const c_char = ptr::null();
    let r = unsafe { pam_get_user(pamh, &mut raw_user, ptr::null()) };
    if raw_user.is_null() {
        Err(r)
    } else {
        let user = unsafe {CStr::from_ptr(raw_user)};
        Ok(user.to_owned())
    }
}
```

If you want to avoid allocation, you should create some context object.

> "The pam_end function terminates the PAM transaction and is the last function an application should call in the PAM context. Upon return the handle pamh is no longer valid and all memory associated with it will be invalid. "

```
struct TransactionContext{
   pamh: PamHandleT
}

impl Drop for TransactionContext{
  fn drop(&mut self){
     unsafe {pam_end(pamh);}
  }
}

pub fn get_user(pamh: &TransactionContext) -> PamResult<&CStr> {
    let mut raw_user: *const c_char = ptr::null();
    let r = unsafe { pam_get_user(pamh.pamh, &mut raw_user, ptr::null()) };
    if raw_user.is_null() {
        Err(r)
    } else {
        let user = unsafe {CStr::from_ptr(raw_user)};
        Ok(user)
    }
}
```

This would make result CStr to have same lifetime as TransactionContext and borrow checker would ensure that you don't use result CStr after your TransactionContext is dropped.